# Im trying to split two strings in separate lists and then compare them but im getting "unhashable type: 'list'" error

Tags: python

Im trying to get the difference between 2 strings and I go about it by turning them into two lists and than comparing them. Like this:

```
str1 = ['apple_red_big']
str2 = ['apple_red_small']
a = [i.split('_') for i in str1]
b = [j.split('_') for j in str2]
set_difference = set(a) - set(b)
list_difference = list(set_difference)

print(list_difference)
```

Im trying to get a string "small" or "big" but im getting a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.
If I change "a" and "b" to just to experiment:

```
a = ['apple', 'red', 'big']
b = ['apple', 'red', 'small']
```

It works just fine and its still a list right?
What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks guys

Comment: `[i.split('_') for i in str1]` looks wrong anyways. It looks like you actually want just `a = str1.split("_")`. If you check what `a` and `b` are holding, I don't think they have what you're expecting.

Comment: Is this a typo or? `set_difference = set(b) - set(c)` set(c) and not set(b) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Why are `str1` and `str2` lists? They should be strings. i.e. `str1 = 'apple_red_big'` and then `a = str1.split('_')`. Currently you have `a` as a list of lists so that can't be turned to a set

Comment: Uhh yes its a typo. Should be `set(a) - set(b)`

Comment: Im sorry I wasnt clear.

Comment: I recommend you to do: `print("apple_red_big".split('_'))` and see how the output looks. It might give you a clue about the problem

Comment: Im sorry I wasnt clear.
As of now it doesnt make sense str1 to be a list but the original idea is str1 to be a long list of multiply strings like this example:

`str1 = ['apple_red_big', 'orange_orange_big']
str2 = ['apple_red_small', 'orange_orange_small']`


Im trying to pair the apples in the two strings in some way. 
The strings are objects in Maya actually and im trying to write a script that if one apple is selected it automatically adds the other respective apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the strings and lists inside lists which is unnecessary if you not comparing more than 2 strings. The code below is what you are looking for.

```
str1 = 'apple_red_big'
str2 = 'apple_red_small'
a = str1.split('_')
b = str2.split('_')
set_difference = set(b) - set(a)
list_difference = list(set_difference)

print(list_difference)
```

If str1 and str2 contains more than one string and the same amount of strings you can solve it like this:

```
str1 = ['apple_red_big','apple_red_big']
str2 = ['apple_red_small','apple_red_small']
a = [i.split('_') for i in str1]
b = [j.split('_') for j in str2]
list_difference = []
for i in range(len(str1)):
    set_difference = set(b[i]) - set(a[i])
    list_difference += list(set_difference)
print(list_difference)
```

Comment: Second part is absolutely what im looking for. Thanks @Sefan . And what if I want to get the first matching parts of the strings (apple_red)?

Comment: @BaiS Adding something like this should get you the matching parts: list_matching += list(set(b[i])-set_difference)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming str1 and str2 are list of string as described, str1 could be :

```
['apple_red_big', 'banana_blue_small']
```

then doing :

```
a = [i.split('_') for i in str1]
```

gives you :

```
[['apple', 'red', 'big'], ['banana', 'blue', 'small']]
```

So you're trying to make a set from a list of list, which doesn't work.

You could loop through that list and sub list to add elements to a set
like :

```
your_set = set()
for sublist in a:
    for elm in sublist:
        your_set.add(elm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
str1 = ['apple_red_big']
str2 = ['apple_red_small']
a = str1.split('_')
b = str2.split('_')
set_difference = set(a) - set(b)
list_difference = list(set_difference)

print(list_difference)
```

Splitting the list will itself create a new list. So you can proceed with finding the unique elements